# How to merge 2 tables using yii

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have 2 tables:

```
Transport {transID, name}
```

and

```
Fuel {id,average, comb, urban}
```

How can I use Table `Fuel` in my `Transport` table Controller? I want to have an array of records from 2 tables.

-edit-
I want 1 to 1 relation using transID and id.

Comment: Could you include an example of what exactly you want?

Comment: Is it possible for a transport to have many "fuels" or just one "fuel"? Those are different answers to the question ...

Comment: Are you working with models for these tables? If you have developed or generated the models the right way you are able to access one model from the other (one fuel from transport and many transports from fuel).

Answer (score 0):

An oversimplified example of getting the Transport model en referenced Fuel model in your controller can be

**Transport model**

```
class Transport extends ActiveRecord {
::
    public function getFuel()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Fuel::className(), ['id' => 'transID']);
    }
::
}
```

**Fuel model **

```
class Fuel extends ActiveRecord {
::
    public function getTransport()
    {
            return $this->hasOne(Transport::className(), ['transID' => 'id']);
    }
::
}
```

**Transport controller**

```
class TransportController extends Controller {
::

    public function actionView($id) {
        //get transport
        $transport = Transport::find()->where(['transID' => $id])->one();

        /*
        * access Fuel model with $transport->fuel and do anything you like
        * including converting the data to an array
        */
    }
::
}
```